# related articles using shortcodes

Tags: categories, shortcode

I want to make related articles based on the categories in the sidebar using shortcodes so that they can be placed anywhere. can you help me? thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add the shortcode is to create a shortcode in your child theme functiuons.php  file.

```
function footag_func( $atts ) {            //Example
    return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'footag', 'footag_func' );
```

You can refer to this document for WordPress shortcodes detail

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: how do you make related articles by category?